# Mapear array en php

Tags: php

Estimados necesito mapear informacion en `php`, tengo dos `json` con distinto nombres de atributos pero la misma informacion.
¿Cómo podría hacer que por medio de un `array` pueda mapear en informacion para luego utilizarla?
Por ejemplo `{id:1}` deberia ser igual a `{codigo:1}` y luego segurramente rento que recorrerlo con `foreach`.

ejemplo :

```
Primer array {"object":{"id":"19","nombre":nombre,"apellido":apellido,"secure_key":"123"}}

Segundo array {"codigo":"19","name":nombre,"lastname":apellido,"password":"123"}}
```

Pero imaginemos que tengo arrays de mas de 1000 registros, como podria hacer para cruzar la informacion entre los array?

Comment: Si fueras tan amable de compartir una muestra de los datos que planeas tratar, así como lo que llevaras al momento sería genial.

Comment: @Aprendiz ahi edite la consulta..

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo del resultado que querés obtener? Entiendo por donde va la pregunta pero no del todo lo que querés hacer.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que yo haría es trabajar con el json en formato string para modificar sus keys con mayor facilidad y luego convertirlo en el array de php:

```
$jsonString = '{"object":{"id":"19","nombre":"nombre","apellido":"apellido","secure_key":"123"}}';
// Cambiamos las keys por las que nos interesan
$jsonString = str_replace('"id:', '"codigo":', $jsonString);
$jsonString = str_replace('"nombre:', '"name":', $jsonString);
$jsonString = str_replace('"apellido:', '"lastname":', $jsonString);
// etc.

// Convertimos el json en un array asociativo
$jsonArray = json_decode($jsonString, true)["object"];

var_dump($jsonArray);
```

Con esto podrías tener un array idéntico al del segundo json.

Answer (score 1):

```
Puedes hacer lo siguiente:



$data = json_decode([
{"id":"19","nombre":nombre,"apellido":apellido,"secure_key":"123"}, 
{"id":"20","nombre":nombre,"apellido":apellido,"secure_key":"456"}, 
{"id":"21","nombre":nombre,"apellido":apellido,"secure_key":"789"}
]);

$result=[];

foreach($data as $key=>$registro){
      $persona = new /stdClass();
      $persona->codigo = $registro->id;
      $persona->name= $registro->nombre;
      $persona->lastname = $registro->apellido;
      $persona->password = $registro->secure_key;
      $result[$key]=$persona;
}

var_dump($result);
```

si son muchos registros puedes usar array_chunk() para 
    procesar el array por partes